# Populate angular ui grid from multiple sources (two)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ui-grid

Is it possible to populate the same table with data from multiple sources (API and for example Redis)?

I'm trying to reproduce ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/myW9da9BwahaMSvvQDYL?p=preview)) this situation, but I cannot simulate incoming data from Redis.

There is a two function for getting data from multiple source:

**1) getDataFromAPI()** - working function for getting data from JSON

```
 function getDataFromAPI() {
     $http.get('load.json').success(function (data) {
          data.forEach(function( row, index ) {
              $scope.myData.push(data);
          });
          $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
          console.log('api data', data);
     })
};
```

**2)    getDataFromRedis()** - getting data from source 2 (Redis) and show in the same table

```
function getDataFromRedis(msg) {
    $scope.myData.push(msg);
};
getDataFromRedis();
```

Comment: Why are you not iterating on the data coming in from Redis? You're only pushing the returned set. 

If I understand correctly, I would think you'd either want to iterate the returned set and push each of those into $scope.myData or concatenate the arrays, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: Data from Redis come from channel one by one. I'll try with concatenating.